# Removing an option from dropbox after selected

Tags: php, list, session, dropdown

I have a state guessing guess I wrote. I'm trying to remove a capital from the dropbox menu after it has been guessed. Any clues on how to go about doing that?

I have a comment on line 44 which is code that I believe may work but I havent been able to get working.

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance!
Heres my code:

```
<?php
require_once "include/session.php";
if (!isset($session->valid)) {
  header("location: login.php");
  exit();
}
require_once "include/city_info.php";

/* DO NOT MODIFY THE ABOVE LINES !!!!! */

$states   = array_keys($state_capitals);
$capitals = array_values($state_capitals);
$cities   = array_merge($capitals, $other_cities);
sort($cities);

$params = (object) $_REQUEST;


if (isset ($params->guess) ) {
$state = $session->statename;
$capital = $params->city;
$city = $params->city;
$session->guess ++ ;

//if they guess correctly
if ($capital == $state_capitals[$session->statename]){
$response = "You've Guessed Correct After $session->guess Guesses";
}

//if they guess incorrectly
else {
$response = " You've Guessed Wrong $session->guess Times";}
}

else {
$index = rand( 0, count($states)- 1 );
$state = $states[ $index ];
$city = $state_capitals[ $state ];
$session->statename = $state;
$guess = (0);
$session->guess = (0);
$response = "Try To Get Less Than 3 Guesses";

 // create initial selections
  //$session->selections = array();
 // foreach($city as $value) {
   // $session->selections[$value] = 1;
  //}

}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" 
      content="no-cache, max-age=0, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<title>State Capital Guessing Game</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-color:#ffff4d;
}

div {
    position:center;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    background-color:#3399ff;

}


}
h1{
padding:5px;
}

h2 {
text-align: center;
font-size:20px;
}

h3 {
text-align:center;
}

h4 {
text-align:center;
}

h5 {
position: absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
}

#logout {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a id="logout" href="logout.php">Log out</a>

<h1>
State Capital Guess Game
<form action="program.php" method="get">
<button type="submit">Reset</button>
</h1>
</form>

<div>
<form action="program.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="answer" value="<?php echo $state?>" />


  <h2>
  Guess the capital of: <?php echo "$session->state" ?>
  </h2>
 <h3>
  <select name="city">
<?php
    $options = "";
    foreach ($cities as $value){
        $options .= '<option value="' . $value . '"';
        if ($value == $params->city)
            $options .= ' selected';
        $options .= '>' . $value . '</option>';
    }
    echo $options;
?>
</select>
  <input type="submit" name="guess" value="Guess" />
  </form>
  </h3>
  <h4><?php echo $response ?></h4>
  </div>

<h5><?php echo "The Correct Answer Is: $state_capitals[$state]" ?><h5>



</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Hmm... This looks familiar! Glad to see you're further with this. What's the error that you're seeing when you uncomment that section of code?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to create a part of the game that 'remembers' what has already been selected. Correct? To 'remember' something, you'll need to use either a database or a cookie. You need to decide also how detailed you'll want this to be, because that will determine whether you use the database or the cookie. If you want it to be an game that individuals play (like solitaire) or a game that groups can play (WoW - using the same information across the globe). You're probably going to just want to use a cookie (individual) as it should be the least complicated.